# Using CBV form_invalid() method to update Model object

Tags: python, django

I want to update existing object in the Model. But I am using `form_invalid(self, form)` for this.

```
**views.py**
class SomeClassView(UpdateView):
    model = Some
    form_class = SomeForm
    template_name = 'some.html'

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        Some.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk']).update(**form.cleaned_data)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.POST['redirect_url'])

**urls.py**
url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', SomeclassView.as_view(), name='edit'),
```

I create new objects in my model the same way in my other class, but however I cant update it and I get this error:

```
AttributeError at /edit/1/
'Some' object has no attribute 'update'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `get()` does not return a queryset. Instead, it returns an instance of the model.

Try replacing

```
Some.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk']).update(**form.cleaned_data)
```

with

```
Some.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['pk']).update(**form.cleaned_data)
```

Read the [Queryset API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) for more info.